# How to turn on rEFInd in the startup again?

Tags: dual-boot, refind

I formatted an old MacBook and installed:

1. MacOS El Capitan
2. rEFInd boot manager
3. Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela MATE with codecs (64-bit)

At first both OSs installed. When rebooting it still loads to rEFInd boot manager, but after that, restarting again, it will either go straight to Linux Mint or I have to press the Option (<kbd>Alt</kbd>) key to show macOS and Recovery disk 2 drives only.

How do I turn on rEFInd boot manager again?

Answer (score 1):

I installed the rEFind boot loader again in Mas os and restart, it works fine then.